# GitHub personal token for PhpStorm

Tags: github, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm looking at connecting my GitHub account in the version control section of PhpStorm. The JetBrains guide suggests using a personal token but as I'm new to personal tokens in GitHub I'm unsure when creating the personal token what scopes I should be selecting so that it can work but doesn't have to much access.

Can someone please let me know which options I should be selecting and why?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about the scopes in "[About scopes for OAuth Apps](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-integrations/setting-up-and-registering-oauth-apps/about-scopes-for-oauth-apps/)".

In your case, as described in "[Pushing to remote Git repository from a build](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/git-push/#creating-github-personal-access-token)"

> The scope needed is **`public_repo`** for a public repository or **`repo`** for a private repository.

- **public_repo**

> Grants read/write access to code, commit statuses, collaborators, and deployment statuses for public repositories and organizations. Also required for starring public repositories.

- **repo**

> Grants read/write access to code, commit statuses, invitations, collaborators, adding team memberships, and deployment statuses for public and private repositories and organizations.